# How to get the selected time from datetimepicker in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

`datetimepicker.Value` or `datetimepicker.Text` is always returning the current `DateTime`, not the selected one. Is there any property that I need to set to get the selected date time.
Below is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    c1.cName = textBox1.Text;
    c1.dlv_Time = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    string temp = dateTimePicker1.Text;
    textBox1.Text = "";
    dateTimePicker1.Text = "";

}
```

In the Form UI, I am changing the time, but in the code Im always receiving the present time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In which part of code you are trying to read time from DateTimePicker?

Comment: c1.dlv_Time = dateTimePicker1.Value; in button1_click event, Im trying to store the selected value in c1.dlv_time variable

Comment: So reduce code to initialization of control and then reading the value and say what do you receive and why it's unexpected. To be honest, currently, for me it's unclear what is the question. It's hard to follow the code.

Comment: `dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay` contains time part and `dateTimePicker1.Value.Date` contains date part. And you can get suitable string representation using format strings which you need.

Comment: I am changing the time in user interface, so I need to get this selected time. whenever I try to get, it is giving me the current time not the selected time.

Comment: Maybe you are reading time from another control rather than the one which you change in UI. To ask such question, it's enough to use a single `DateTimePicker`, some initialization code and a button click event handler which contains `MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString());`. Then you will see there is no problem with value of the control.

Comment: That's why posting [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is important. It helps you to solve the problem yourself at the first step. After that, it helps us to reproduce the problem and help you solve it.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. I was reading from different datetimepicker. Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 1):

`dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString()`

It will return you the selected time of the date picker control in the string format.

Answer (score 0):

I was editing a different timepicker and reading from a different timepicker.
I have resolved it by changing datetimepicker1 to datetimepicker2.